# Implementation of Google authentication (OAuth) in CAS

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, cas, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google authentication (OAuth) in CAS 4.1.9.

First of all I have created a new project on console.developers.google.com in which I have generated a new client id for my application.

Then, I have installed CAS using Maven overlays. In my pom.xml I included the pac4j dependency as it follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>pac4j-oauth</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Moreover,this is what I have added in my applicationContext.xml file:

```
<bean id="GoogleAuthenticationHandler"
   class="org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client"
   p:key="<MYKEY>"
   p:secret="<MYSECRET>"
   p:scope="EMAIL_AND_PROFILE" />

<bean id="clients"
   class="org.pac4j.core.client.Clients">
   <property name="callbackUrl" value="https://myapplication.com/cas" />
   <property name="clients">
     <list>
       <ref bean="GoogleAuthenticationHandler" />
     </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

And finally I have added the following line in casLoginView.jsp

```
<a href="${Google2ClientUrl}">Authenticate with Google</a> <br />
```

The maven compilation worked fine and the war file deployed successfully on my tomcat server.

The problem is that the href to Google in my CAS login web page does not contain the correct OAuth url but the same redirect url I have defined for my client under console.developers.google.com.

As second attempt I tried to substitute ${Google2ClientUrl} with the OAuth url:

```
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https://myapplication.com/cas&response_type=code&client_i
d=<MY CLIENT ID>&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.re
adonly+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline">Authenticate with Google</a> <br />
```

In this case the Google login page shows up and it accepts user authentication, but it seems that CAS does not recognize a successfully user authentication by Google (i.e. it does not show the normal page containing the authentication success message).

Did I miss something?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to include your code. The callback happens here: https://myapplication.com/cas

Comment: Which code should I include exactly? The only modifications I have made to CAS configuration are already reported above. I did not modify any other source/configuration CAS file.

Comment: First rule about StackOverflow: Include everything needed to reproduce your problem. I gave you a hint that the problem is the callback URL. Include the source code that impements that URL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by installing a newer version of CAS (5.3.6). Here the Google authenticator  configuration is much easier.  Actually only two steps are needed :

1) add pac4j dependency in the pom.xml file

```
     <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
               <artifactId>cas-server-support-pac4j-webflow</artifactId>
               <version>${cas.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

2) add the Google authenticator parameter in the cas.properties file:

```
       cas.authn.pac4j.google.id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>
       cas.authn.pac4j.google.secret=<MY_SECRET>
       cas.authn.pac4j.google.clientName=<MY_CLIENT_NAME>
       cas.authn.pac4j.google.autoRedirect=false
       cas.authn.pac4j.google.principalAttributeId=
       cas.authn.pac4j.google.scope=EMAIL_AND_PROFILE
```

Once this is done a link to Google authentication shows up in the CAS login page automatically.